# Get BLOB from stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE prodecureName
  (
    firstArgument IN NUMBER,
    secondArgument OUT BLOB )
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT secondArgument 
  INTO prodecureName.secondArgument 
  FROM tableName
  WHERE firstArgument = prodecureName.firstArgument ;
END;
```

Data type of secondArgument column is valid (both are BLOB).
During executing this procedure I get this error:

> Wrong number or types of arguments in call to prodecureName

How I can get blob from stored procedure?

Comment: Can you post the calling code, too? The error is likely to be there

Comment: Code doesn't matter. I try to call this procedure from SQL Developer. I get this same error.

Comment: It does matter, because it seems to be wrong the way you call it...

Comment: How do you call it in SQL Developer?

Comment: Now It's working. I changed from BLOB to CLOB in procedure and table. I don't know how, but it's working now...

Answer (score 1):

One way to call this procedure:

```
declare
  l_blob blob;
begin
  procedurename(1,l_blob);
end;
```

The error message indicates that you are calling this with the wrong type of parameters or the wrong number of parameters. First parameter must by of type number, second parameter of type blob.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (using clob instead of blob, but same approach):

```
drop table tst_clob_tab;
create table tst_clob_tab
(
  id number,
  my_clob clob
);

-- Oracle will implicitly convert to clob (9i greater)
insert into tst_clob_tab(id,my_clob) values (1,'This is some large value...');
commit;

-- Create procedure
create or replace procedure tst_clob(p_1 in number, p_2 out clob) as
begin
  select my_clob
  into p_2
  from tst_clob_tab
  where id = p_1;
end;

-- Call procedure
declare
  l_clob clob;
begin
  tst_clob(1,l_clob);
  dbms_output.put_line('Clob: ' || l_clob);
end;
```